# kpackagekit hangs

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I just installed kubuntu 11.04 and the problem I have is that kpackagekit "froze" while installing updates. It froze while installing some plasma widgets.
So my question is how can I disable the updating process without breaking the system and what is the most recommended way to install updates on kubuntu (I have realized that kpackagekit is really buggy)?

Answer (score 1):

i also had issue with kpackagekit which forced me to install synaptic, this wasn't ideal but worked well until i found muon.

it is very similar to synaptic but coded in Qt and it is set to replace kpackagekit for Oneric

More info [here](http://www.wonderly.com/2011/05/muon-kde-package-manager-and-software-center/)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the computer and ran `sudo apt-get update` and then after a few steps the problem is fixed.
From what I read the better way to maintain the system is through the terminal and not kpackagekit.